# Checkboxes not checked despite value being true

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am having a problem with my column updating, as far as I can see it's updating fine but for some reason the actual checkboxes that should be getting checked aren't. I can't seem to figure out why as all the values are set as true.

```
using (IDbConnection connection = sessionFactory.ConnectionProvider.GetConnection())
{
    if (TableExists(connection, "tbl_ecom_cat_feature") && 
        ColumnExists(connection, "tbl_ecom_cat_feature", "display_on_search"))
    {
        using (IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_ecom_cat_feature SET display_on_search = 1";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I have just realised that in my Checkbox_Check method I haven't actually put anything in to check if it's checked... I'm actually unsure how I would grab the data from the SQL column to see if it's true and if it is, return the box as checked.

Code in which I display the checkboxes:

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
    if (value != null && value is string)
        {
        var input = (string)value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("Name"))
            {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    return Visibility.Visible;
}
```

and the WPF code in which these checkboxes are displayed is as follows:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Display On Search">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding StringToVisibilityConverter}" IsChecked="{Binding StringToVisibilityConverter}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>                            
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: You need to show us the code where you retrieve your data and bind your checkboxes...

Comment: I accidentally posted this before finishing the thread, give me a minute.

Comment: I don't see any check boxes in this code.  All I see is a SQL query which will set a value to 1 for every record in the table.  Where are the check boxes?

Comment: Please add the *relevant* code or we can't help you. This is your SQL query which isn't causing a problem - if your issue is with where you retrieve the values or create your checkboxes then thats the coded you need to give us.

Comment: As I noted in the edit, I've realised I didn't actually do my databinding but I am actually unsure how I would grab the information from the Database in C#, therefore there is no code actually retrieving the values, I will post my code where the checkboxes are created in case this is any use.

Comment: I hope the information I have provided give's a little clearer idea.

Comment: You are binding IsChecked to visibility converter and not passing a value.  -1

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, please read the OP before downvoting.

Comment: @NortonTaylor - What is your DataContext? What is the name of the (boolean) field you want to base the checkbox's check/uncheck value on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your properties to a value from your `datacontext` and then assign the converter in the binding, so it will convert your source value, to a target value. Code:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Display On Search">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding sourceProp, Converter={StaticResource myStringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>                            
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

and your will need to specify your converter as a resource like:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <con:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="myStringToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

the resource could also be set on another level in the `XAML` eg. the gridview.